# Multiple Users option not coming on my page

Tags: apex, lookup, tasks, event, lookup-filter

While creating a task when we click on the lookup icon of assigned-to pop up appears where we can search for user and also assign the task to multiple users or groups. But when I made a vf page those options are missing, there is only search bar. 
When clicked from task layout the option comes.

[image]

When clicked from vf page options are not coming.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.